Using TinyMCE as a web component
I want to use v6 of TinyMCE and i want to use it as a web component. What version of tinymce-webcomponent should i use please?
I tried using current version of TinyMCE (6.8.3) and two versions of web-component library (2.1.0 and 1.2.0).
Then i use this line from the documentation:
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-webcomponent';
In both cases i get this error: 'Editor' is not exported by ..\..\node_modules\@tinymce\tinymce-webcomponent\dist\tinymce-webcomponent.js. I assume that the problem is in incompatibility of those libraries.
